# Visualizing index build?

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

What kind of visualizations/statistics can I get from PostGIS' GiST index?

If we look at [Wikipedia's R-tree entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree), there are different R-tree variations and visualizations of bounding boxes of each using ELKI. GiST index is similar to R-Tree index. So is there some method/ extension for this kind of visualization (perhaps through QGIS)?

Edit: [Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170728104949/http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/postgis-intro/clusterindex.html) it is also visualized - how is this achieved?

Comment: Interesting question. For what it is worth, spatial indexes are actually implemented using GIST in Postgres (which is a generalization allow more specific indexes such  as R-trees to be constructed), so you will probably need to drill down into some [internals](http://www.sai.msu.su/~megera/wiki/GiST), which can get scary quite fast. For what is is worth, the Geohashing clustering outlined in the Boundless link actually uses B-tree indexing, it is just that geohashes tend to put things geographically close together, close together in their hash representation.

Comment: Yes, GiST is used. But since it functions similar to R-tree on 2D data, I was hoping I could visualize at least that. QGIS can visualize some data so I was hoping this functionality existed.

Comment: I think this is a much better question for [dba.se]

Answer (score 2):

The [Gevel](http://www.sai.msu.su/~megera/oddmuse/index.cgi/Gevel) contrib module provides several functions useful for analyzing GIN and GiST indexes.