# Read R-Tree from PostGIS enabled database

Tags: postgis, rtree

There is a method available to get the largest rectangle from the R-Tree ([see this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/282673/getting-the-largest-rectangle-in-the-r-tree-index-of-a-postgis-table)). Are there methods available that allow one to read the entire tree?

Comment: Try if Gevel still exists https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/230838/visualizing-index-build. Image from the Gevel documentation http://www.sai.msu.su/~megera/oddmuse/images/cities-l-2.gif.